# spring @Value annotation, inheritance and common fields but different values

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have three classes and one is a superclass.

```
class abstract Base {
   public abstract String getV();
}

class A extends Base {
   private String v;
   @Value("${A.v}") public String getV() { return v; };
}

class B extends Base {
   private String v;
   @Value("${B.v}") public String getV() { return v; };
}
```

Is there any way to simplify the use of spring @Value annotation? I don't want to copy-paste field declaration and the getter for all Base children. All I get so far is:

```
class abstract Base {
   protected String v;
   public String getV() { return v; };
   public abstract void setV(String v);
}

class A extends Base {
   @Value("${A.v}") public void setV(String v) { this.v = v;};
}

class B extends Base {
   @Value("${B.v}") public void setV(String v) { this.v = v;};
}
```

Is there any more efficient way? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are A.v and B.v actually?

Comment: There are pathes for fields values in the configuration file.

Naturally, "A.v" should be "${A.v}", same with "B.v".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I doubt it.  Annotations CANNOT be dynamic.  There's no way to put any kind of annotation on the abstract setV method which will adapt to the subclass.  What you've done is really the right way to go.

However i'd modify your code slightly:

```
class Base {
   private String v;
   public String getV() { return v; };
   public void setV(String v) { this.v = v; }
}

class A extends Base {
   @Value("${A.v}") public String setV(String v) { super.setV(v); }
}

class B extends Base {
   @Value("${B.v}") public String setV(String v) { super.setV(v); }
}
```

I've had this issue not only with @Value annotations, but with @Resource/@Qualifier annotations as well.

This is a big reason i'm not a huge fan of autowiring.  I've found myself making a bunch of subclasses for no reason other than to autowire things with different qualifiers/values.

Another alternative might be java based configuration.  I know it's not a huge departure from doing it in XML, but i find it cleaner than xml, and certainly better than overriding all your setters.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Value("${A.v}")
    private String av;

    @Value("${B.v}")
    private String bv;

    @Bean
    public A a() {
       A a = new A();
       a.setV(av);
    }


    @Bean
    public B b() {
       B b = new B();
       b.setV(bv);
    }
}
```

And then in your XML:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean class="MyConfig" />
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
class abstract Base {
    private String v;
    protected void configure(String v) {
        this.v = v;
    }
}

class A extends Base {
    @Value("${A.v}") private String v;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @PostConstruct
    private void configure() {
        super.configure(v);
    }
}

class B extends Base {
    @Value("${B.v}") private String v;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")        
    @PostConstruct
    private void configure() {
        super.configure(v);
    }
}
```

This way, if you have lots of values you need to set in the superclass, you only need one instance variable for each, and can set them all in the configure method. Granted you aren't forced to implement configure!

Comment: Sorry - ignore me. I should have tried it first :-C: "Cannot refer to an instance field wsdlUrl while explicitly invoking a constructor". Kind of obvious if I'd thought about it! Would work with a @PostConstruct, but then you're not enforced to call that, so you're back to an abstract method!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question...
I got the similar challenge recently and could solve it using the following approach in spring boot application.

I have a parent class with @Value annotation:

```java
package com.example.propertytest;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class PropertyParent {
    @Value("${value}")
    String value;
}
```

And also have child classes PropertyChild1, PropertyChild2:

```java
package com.example.propertytest;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "root.prefix1")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")
public class PropertyChild1 extends PropertyParent {
}
```

```java
package com.example.propertytest;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "root.prefix2")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")
public class PropertyChild2 extends PropertyParent {
}
```

Annotations `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "root.prefix1")` , `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "root.prefix2")` specify prefix for my values in **application.yaml** file:

```yaml
root:
  prefix1:
    value: a
  prefix2:
    value: b
```

Check whether it works could be done, for example, via such TestClass:

```java
package com.example.propertytest;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    PropertyChild1 propertyChild1;

    @Autowired
    PropertyChild2 propertyChild2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void info(){
        log.info(propertyChild1.toString());
        log.info(propertyChild2.toString());
    }
}
```

I have the following result:

```
  PropertyParent(value=a)
  PropertyParent(value=b)
```

However, if I put configuration not in **application.yaml** file, but in any another, like **properties.yaml** and will change annotation
`@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")`
to
`@PropertySource("classpath:properties.yaml")`
this would not work.

Still wonder why though...